# TextField multiline if needed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the text field in flutter to be single line by default. But when user writes a text that does not fit in the single line, I want the text field to become 2 lines, and then 3 lines if 2 lines do not fit. When text does not fit in 3 lines I don't want the number of lines to expand to 4. A similar concept is used in WhatsApp app when writing a message in text field.

```
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
   maxLines: 3,
)
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, Please accept that too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add minLines=1 in your code,

```
TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: 3,
          minLines: 1,
        ),
```